# My JFrame appears in basic design not in advanced design in java netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, look-and-feel, nimbus

Recently I made a desktop application for login system, I always run the program if i changed any code to be sure if this code is working well or not, Anyways when I run the program it always appears as an advanced design, I don't know what you call it.Let the images explain.

Basic design

http://www5.0zz0.com/2013/04/10/14/418370274.jpg

Advanced design

http://www5.0zz0.com/2013/04/10/14/868362737.jpg

Comment: what is the problem you are having and what have you done so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic design is basically Metal Look And Field and Advanced Design is Nimbus Look And Field so use the following code before creating object of the JFrame class.

```
try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

This code will change any look and field to Nimbus Look and Field